# Saving symbol-names of argument in macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp

One of the exercises in Paul Grahams ANSI Common Lisp book is this: Define a macro that takes a list of variables and a body of code, and ensures that the variables revert to their original values after the body of code is evaluated.

The problem I'm having with this exercise is how to save the symbol-names of the input variables. Below I have a start where I only save the values that the symbols are bound to.

```
(defmacro save-run (varlist &body body)
  `(let ((valuelist (list ,@varlist)))
    (format t "valuelist: ~A" valuelist)))

(let ((a 5)(b 6))
  (values '(a b))
  (save-run (a b) 
        (setf a 7)
        (setf b 8)))

[507]> valuelist: (5 6)
```

Edit: Here's a solution where the variables are saved and then restored (using tips from finnw below). But shadowing the variables as in Vatine's answer is probably more elegant.

```
(defmacro save-run (varlist &body body)
  `(let ((valuelist (list ,@varlist)))
     ,@body
     (multiple-value-setq ,varlist (values-list valuelist))))
```

Comment: You don't need `(progn ,@body)`.  Just `,@body` will have the same effect.

Comment: If you use `(setf (values ,@varlist) ...)` instead of `(multiple-value-setq ,varlist ...)` then some of the variables can be places other than symbols, e.g. `(save-run ((cdr x)) ...)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. I looked in the documentation and setf can only take an even number of arguments assigned in pairs, not lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the list of symbols, all you need to do is quote the contents of `VARLIST`:

```
(defmacro save-run (varlist &body body)
  `(let ((namelist ',varlist)
         (valuelist (list ,@varlist)))
    (format t "namelist: ~A~%" namelist)
    (format t "valuelist: ~A~%" valuelist)))
```

I suspect this will not be useful in the final defnition however.  There is not much you can do with the list of symbols at run-time.  Instead, look for a good place to insert the list in the macro expansion.

Also you might want to use a `GENSYM` instead of the hard-coded variable name `VALUELIST`:

```
(defmacro save-run (varlist &body body)
  (let ((valuelist (gensym)))
    `(let ((,valuelist (list ,@varlist)))
       ,@body
       (setf (values ,@varlist) (values-list ,valuelist)))))
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know that you can combine quote and comma like that.

Comment: Sorry I should have said don't use *namelist*, you do need the value list. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd introduce another binding layer for the variables we want to save.

You have the list of variables in `varlist` so something like this may work:

```
(defmacro save-run (varlist &body body)
  `(let ,(loop for var in varlist
               collect (list var var))
     ,@body))
```

Comment: I like it, more elegant than saving and restoring.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked Vatine's approach. Here is an implementation that expands to the same code, but uses mapcar instead of the loop macro:

```
(defmacro save-run (varlist &body body)
  `(let ,(mapcar #'list varlist varlist)
     ,@body))
```